# iOS 9 UIImagePickerController video mode blurry

Tags: ios, video, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ios9

I'm using an `UIImagePickerController` to capture a video and store it. When I try it with still image capturing everything works fine, but when I open the `UIImagePickerController` in video mode, the picture is always a bit blurry. When I try to focus a different object i see a change in focus but it is still a little bit blurry (so never really in focus). Is this a known issue with `iOS 9`? I also tried some sample projects from the internet but with the same result. I tried it with my `iPhone 6s` as well as an `iPhone 6`.

here is the code I used:

```
    func actionSheet(sheet: ActionSheet, didSelectOption option: Int) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let statusView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame)
    statusView.y = (-(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height))
    statusView.backgroundColor = colorBlue
    picker.navigationBar.insertSubview(statusView, atIndex: 1)


    if sheet.tag == actionSheetTagTakePicture {
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = option == 1 ? .Camera : .PhotoLibrary
        if option == 1 {
            picker.cameraDevice = .Front
        }
    }
    else {
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        picker.sourceType = option == 1 ? .Camera : .SavedPhotosAlbum
        if option == 1 {
            picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Rear

            picker.cameraDevice = .Rear
            picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Video
        }
    }
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: having same problem in iOS 13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, turns out that the default settings for `.videoQuality` are `.TypeMedium`. Which resulted in:

- video dimensions are 4:3
- video quality was bad on the large display -> so it looked as it was blurred (or actually was because of the bad quality)

I changed the settings like this:

```
picker.videoQuality = .TypeIFrame960x540
```

now everything works fine and the video is also 16:9